# How to upload several images & automatically create an entry for each one?

Tags: image, upload

I have more than 1000 images that I want to upload on Craft. Is there any way to bulk upload all the images and automatically create one entry for each one of them? Including their fields, like categories and tags?

Answer (score 3):

I was going to suggest using the very handy [Import plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import), but I see that it only supports entries, categories, and users. And unfortunately, I don't see another plugin that does this specifically. But have a look at the [craft plugins page](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins) in case I missed something.

You might also be able to extend the `Import` plugin (with permission of course) to support assets. I would guess that it would be a similar process. This could potentially allow you to create a CSV file and import it... then upload the images into the location defined in your csv.